# jquery .off(): how to remove a certain click handler only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an element with two handler bound to it:

```
<button class="pippo pluto">
  push me
</button>

$('.pippo').on('click', function () {
    alert("pippo");
});


$('.pluto').on('click', function () {
    alert("pluto");
});
```

I'm trying to .off() only one of them, but the syntax eludes me :-( I'm trying with something among the line of..

```
<button class="dai">
  remove
</button>

$('.dai').on('click', function () {
    $('.pippo').off('click');
  alert("ok, removed");
});
```

but this removes both the handler. So I'm trying with...

```
$('.pippo').off('click .pippo');
```

but then nothing gets removed.

So I removed the middle space:

```
$('.pippo').off('click .pippo');
```

but back to square 1: both handler gets removed.

The right syntax would then be... ?

https://jsfiddle.net/6hm00xxv/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `.off();` method allows you to target multiple selectors as well as a specific event.

- `$('.pippo').off()` would remove all events for the `.pippo` selector.
- `$('.pippo').off('click')` would remove all `click` events for the `.pippo` selector.
- `$('.pippo').off('click', handler)` would remove all `click` events with that handler for the `.pippo` selector.

In your case the `handler` used to add the event listener was an anonymous function so the `handler`cannot be used in the `off()` method to turn off that event.
That leaves you with three options, either use a variable, use a namespace or both.

Its quite simple to figure out which one to use.

```
if( "The same handler is needed more than once" ){
    // you should assign it to a variable,
} else {
    // use an anonymous function. 
}

if ( "I intent to turn off the event" && ( "The handler is an anonymous function" || "I want to turn off multiple listeners for this selector at once" ) ){
    // use a namespace
}
```

In your case

- your handler is only used once so your handler should be an anonymous function.
- you wish to turn off the event and your handler is anonymous so use a namespace.

So it would look like this

```
$('.pippo').on('click.group1', function () {
    alert("pippo");
});

$('.dai').on('click', function () {
    $('.pippo').off('click.group1');
    alert("ok, removed");
});
```

It would work just as well to assign you handler to a variable if you prefer.
This allows you to specify which selector, eventType and handler to remove.

```
var pippo_click = function (e) {
    alert("pippo");
});

$('.dai').on('click', function () {
    $('.pippo').off('click', pippo_click);
    alert("ok, removed");
});
```

But as a rule you shouldn't create variables if they're not needed.

Comment: @Dr.GianluigiZaneZanettini I don't think this answer has the best solution, because you can add the name in where you define your anonymous function, like so: `xxx.click(function handlerName(){$(this).off("click", handlerName)})`

Comment: function handlerName().. is equivalent to $handlerName = function()..

Answer (score 7):

One easier alternative with jQuery is to define a namespace for your click events:

```
$('.pippo').on('click.first', ...);
$('.pluto').on('click.second', ...);

// Remove only the pippo listener
$('.pippo').off('click.first');
```

Note that your classes `pippo` and `pluto` refer to the same element so using one or the other will not change anything.

https://jsfiddle.net/6hm00xxv/2/

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling .off for click event. It is removing all possible click events on that selected element. The trick is to define a handler and remove that particular handler only.

```
function showPluto() {
  showMsg("pluto");
};

function showPippo() {
  showMsg("pippo");
};

function showMsg(text) {
  alert("showMsg called with text: " + text);
};

$('.pippo').on('click', showPippo);
$('.pluto').on('click', showPluto);

$('.dai').on('click', function() {
  $('.pippo').off('click', showPippo);
  alert("ok, removed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved. I just had to bind the handler to document:

```
function showMsg(text) {
    alert("showMsg called with text: " + text);
};

$(document).on('click', '.pippo', function () {
    showMsg("pippo");
});


$(document).on('click', '.pluto', function () {
    showMsg("pluto");
});

$('.dai').on('click', function () {
    $(document).off('click', '.pippo');
  alert("ok, removed");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6hm00xxv/1/

Comment: `$(document)` has a performance hit. you should only need to use this if your elements are dynamically added.

Comment: @TarranJones the performance hit should be negligible with ~10 elements, but still: thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: yea, your right, its says in the docs that it only really makes a differance when it comes to mousemove events.